# countDownTimer Don't show 00:00

Tags: java, android

I'm Making a countdown timer app but the problem when the countdown finish it doesn't show me 00:00 
I'm using seek bar the set the timer when I use 100 in countDown interval it works but I want it to be 1000 in the interval and I'm following a tutorial I write the same code shown in the tutorial it works for him and not for me please help me guys

```
public void buttonClicked(View view)
    {
        CountDownTimer countDown = new CountDownTimer(timerSeek.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timerUpdate((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "finish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }.start();
    }
    /* ========================================================= */


    /* ========================================================= */

public void timerUpdate(int secondsLeft)
    {
        int minutes = secondsLeft / 60;
        int seconds = secondsLeft - (minutes * 60);
            String secondsStr = Integer.toString(seconds);
            if (seconds <= 9)
                secondsStr = "0" + secondsStr;
        timerText.setText(Integer.toString(minutes) + " : " + secondsStr);
    }

    /* ============================================================ */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timerSeek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.timerSeek);
    timerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText);

    timerSeek.setMax(600);
    timerSeek.setProgress(30);

        timerSeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    timerUpdate(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you post your class of `CountDownTimer ` ?

Comment: it's inside the buttonClicked method

Comment: Oh thanks, I got it, I had not use `CountDownTimer` before.

Comment: I test with your code above, and it works as expect (count down 30 sec to "00:00"), so sorry I may not help you..

Comment: that's weird i tested with my phone and two different emulator

Answer (score 0):

This is because **onTick()** method is not called when the countdown is finished. Rather, **onFinish()** is called. An easy solution that appears to me is that you can explicitly show 00:00 inside **onFinish()**, since this method is called when the countdown is finished.

Comment: The problem is the code there is copy past from a video that I watch and the dude from the video worked for him and don't work for me when I change the countdown interval to 100 it works but the countdown go a little bit fast